# Left Join based on field value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I want to get all the detail about my purchase from the following tables,

```
1) tbl_track
2) tbl_album
3) tbl_purchase
```

tbl _purchase table :-

```
item_id
type
price
```

tbl_track table :-

```
id
title
description
```

tbl_album table :-

```
id
title
description
```

Now based on type of tbl_purchase I want to join one of table,
It means If `type = 0` then `LEFT JOIN` with `tbl_track` and for `type = 1` then `LEFT JOIN` with `tbl_album`.

I want to do these with one query only, It is easily done with two query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried a lot of examples but non of worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `UNION`:

```
SELECT p.type, t.id, t.title, t.description
FROM tbl_purchase p
JOIN tbl_track t ON t.id = p.item_id AND p.type = 0
UNION
SELECT p.type, a.id, a.title, a.description
FROM tbl_purchase p
JOIN tbl_album a ON a.id = p.item_id AND p.type = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need left join both tables in any case. So you can use next query for example

```
SELECT P.*,
       T.id AS track_id,
       A.id AS album_id
FROM tbl_purchase AS P
    LEFT JOIN tbl_track AS T ON P.item_id = T.id
                                    AND P.type = 0
    LEFT JOIN tbl_album AS A ON P.item_id = A.item_id
                                    AND P.type = 1
```

Comment: i have appreciate your answer but Its not working for me.

Comment: Why not? Did you have any errors when executed this query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_purchase A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_track B ON A.item_id = B.id AND A.type = 0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_album C ON A.item_id = C.id AND A.type = 1;
```